# Loop help Outputting Multiples properly

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

The program's job is to output all the non-negative multiples of k that are less than n, on one line, and to do that three times using 3 different loops (in this order: while, for, do-while ). Each of the tree times, the multiples (if there are more than one of them) are separated by commas, without a comma before the first number or after the last number.
An example run of your program might go as:

5  40

0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35

0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35

0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35

I am a first time programming student and this is one of my assignments on Visual Studio 2012. I am struggling with all loops and so far have wrote out 2 (while loop, and for loop). Both of my loops output #'s that are way off, nor are the position of the commas in my output statements. Run of My Program:

5 40

,0 ,1 ,6 ,31

0 ,10 ,60

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool die ( const string msg );
void recover();

int main (){
unsigned k, n;
cout <<"Input 2 #'s: " <<endl;
cin >>k >>n || die( "Input Failure" );
if ( k == 0  || n == 0 ) die( "Number Can't Be 0" );
unsigned i = 0;
while( i < n){ //
    cout <<" ," <<i;
    i *= k;
    i++;
    }
cout <<endl;

for( i = 0; i < n; i++){
    recover;
    i *= k;
    cout <<i <<" ,";

}
cout <<endl;

} // main
```

`

Comment: Hint: you can rewrite the series as 0, 0+5, 5+5, 10+5, an so on.

Comment: First rule of programming: *break the problem down into simpler problems.* Don't worry about the commas at first, just get the numbers right. Which of the three loops do you want help with?

Comment: Honestly I need help with all, but lets start with the while loop and maybe I'll learn from there. I also tried to replace i *= k; with i += k (as suggested) but the outputs were also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You know the series should be

```
0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35
```

We'll do the `while` loop. In English, in terms of "while", the program would be "start with 0, then  as long as it's below 40, increase by 5".

```
unsigned i = 0;    // start with 0
while( i < n){     // as long as it's below 40
  cout <<" ," <<i;
  i += k;          // increase by 5
}
cout <<endl;
```

To get the commas right, we must treat either the first number or the last as a special case. That is, we must put ", " either before every number but the first, or after every number but the last. The first is a little easier:

```
unsigned i = 0;    // start with 0
while( i < n){     // as long as it's below 40
  if( i > 0 )
    cout <<" ,";
  cout << i;
  i += k;          // increase by 5
}
cout <<endl;
```

That should be enough to get you started. When you try the `do-while`, if the numbers at the beginning and end aren't quite right, step through the loop on paper-- you must get the order of operations just right. For the `for`, you have three different parameters to play with, the initial value, the end condition and the step size, so just play around with them until you see how to make it give you the sequence you want.

Comment: Really appreciate it! I don't know why I felt the need to have the "i++" that was messing it all up. Thanks again, let you know if I run into trouble with the other loops.

Comment: How do I get proper comma placement for the do-while loop? This is my code so far:
    if ( i > 0 ){
    i = 0;
    do{
    cout <<" ,";
    cout <<i;
    i += k;}while ( i < n );
    cout <<endl;
    }

Comment: @BoyWonder: Think it through, don't just throw code together. The conditional `if(i>0)` should control a part of the code, for the purpose of omitting the comma before the first number.